# Realtime External JSon data (On change)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, external

I'm looking for a way to get Realtime External Json data.

Atm i'm using a javascript timeout that checks the json file, but this makes it that i'm stuck to a "refresh time", and i'm making this system for a notification app from a external json data from a other URL.

I've now been trying websockets such as node.js but i cant manage to find it.

As even i searched everywhere on Stack but i just cant manage to find it.

If someone got a good post about this or a solution to what i should use.

I can use a server thats 24/7, but i prefer it to be on a simple webhosting altought i don't think that is possible for realtime.

Already thanks for your help!

Greetings

Comment: The best way of realtime interaction requires Node.js

Comment: Look at https://socket.io.

Comment: @Striped yhea i've been trying this the last hour or so but without succes. got any post or page,

Comment: The official documentation is good. And you can find a lot of tutorials about it.